# Visual Studio - Find out which dll is not loading

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winui-3

I have a Visual Studio WinUI3 project which crashes on startup because of a .dll which is not found.

The InnerException looks like this:

```
InnerException = {"Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"}

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for '_IAppPageFactory' threw an exception.'
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRT.ActivationFactory`1' threw an exception.
COMException: Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    WinRT.BaseActivationFactory.BaseActivationFactory(string, string) in WinRT.cs
    WinRT.ActivationFactory<T>.ActivationFactory() in WinRT.cs
    WinRT.ActivationFactory<T>.ActivationFactory() in WinRT.cs
```

How do I find out the name of the dll or the name of the class that is not loaded?

The Stacktrace:

```
>   [Exception] Project.Projection.dll!Project.AppPage._IAppPageFactory.Instance.get() Line 387 C#
    [Exception] Project.Projection.dll!Project.AppPage.AppPage() Line 440   C#
    [Exception] ProjectUI.dll!ProjectName.EngineContext.Initialise() Line 31    C#
    [Exception] ProjectUI.dll!ProjectName.MainWindow.Initialse() Line 77    C#
    [External Code] 
    [Waiting on Async Operation, double-click or press enter to view Async Call Stacks] 
    ProjectName.WASDK.dll!ProjectName.WASDK.App.OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) Line 82 C#
    [External Code]
```

Comment: Since that appears to be a COM component that's missing, you could try to search the registry for the GUID in question (if you have that)

Comment: I Couldn't find any GUID, I posted the whole exception.

Comment: That would be near the place where the exception is thrown (e.g. at the call site of the function that throws the exception)

Comment: I added the stacktrace, I cannot say which class is not loaded just from the stacktrace.

Comment: No, you would need to look at parameters within the stack trace. This will require some sophisticated debugging.

Comment: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG doesn't mean a dll is missing, it means a COM (or WinRT) object is not registered properly (and then, maybe a dll is missing after all). You can use Process Monitor from sys internals (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and filter by registry access (and possibly filter on your .exe too). Is IAppPageFactory a component of yours?

Comment: @SimonMourier I encountered the exact same problem on a different project and I fixed it by guessing which dll is missing. AppPageFactory is the class that loads the dlls.

Comment: This error doesn't mean a dll is missing, but maybe a dll is missing.

Comment: @SimonMourier I see. This is what I'm trying to figure out: how do I debug this.

Comment: Did the project succeed? Did the platform architecture or some access rights change? Can a new Winui3 project run successfully?

Comment: In my case this was `CodecQuery` class on Windows 10 Pro N.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to download a Dependency Walker, open the executable there, and click through the dlls and their dependencies to figure out what is missing.  I use this one: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that there are two ways to find which dll is missing:

1. Using GFlags
2. Enabling more exceptions in Visual Studio